# iPhone only lets one side of any earbuds work

Tags: iphone, ear-phones

I just bought new Samsung earbuds and plugged them into my iPhone 4. Only the right side works though. If they're new, why is only one side working? How do I fix my phone itself because I know that it's my phone that isn't working because these are like the 6th new earbuds I've bought that only works on the right side?

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if this is a hardware issue: have you tried with another set of earbuds/headphones?

Answer (score 1):

Double check that you don't have the left/right balance pushed to one side. The slider should be set right in the middle. This is in Settings > general > accessibility > hearing. [image]